# java : get differences between two images

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

i am trying to get difference between two images ( same size ) i found this code :

```
            BufferedImage img1 = null;
            BufferedImage img2 = null;

            try{            
                URL url1 = new URL("http://rosettacode.org/mw/images/3/3c/Lenna50.jpg");
                URL url2 = new URL("http://rosettacode.org/mw/images/b/b6/Lenna100.jpg");
                img1 = ImageIO.read(url1);
                img2 = ImageIO.read(url2);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
             int width1 = img1.getWidth(null);
             int width2 = img2.getWidth(null);
             int height1 = img1.getHeight(null);
             int height2 = img2.getHeight(null);

             if ((width1 != width2) || (height1 != height2)) {
                 System.err.println("Error: Images dimensions mismatch");
                 System.exit(1);
             }

             long diff = 0;
             for (int i = 0; i < height1; i++) {
                 for (int j = 0; j < width1; j++) {
                     int rgb1 = img1.getRGB(i, j);
                     int rgb2 = img2.getRGB(i, j);
                     int r1 = (rgb1 >> 16) & 0xff;
                     int g1 = (rgb1 >>  8) & 0xff;
                     int b1 = (rgb1      ) & 0xff;
                     int r2 = (rgb2 >> 16) & 0xff;
                     int g2 = (rgb2 >>  8) & 0xff;
                     int b2 = (rgb2      ) & 0xff;
                     diff += Math.abs(r1 - r2);
                     diff += Math.abs(g1 - g2);
                     diff += Math.abs(b1 - b2);
                 }
             }
             double n = width1 * height1 * 3;
             double p = diff / n / 255.0;
             System.out.println("diff percent: " + (p * 100.0));    `
```

it works fine for the two images given in the url , but when i changed the images given i get this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:299)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:871)
at Main.main(Main.java:77)
```

I changed the code to :

```
          File sourceimage1 = new File("C:\\lo.jpg");
          File sourceimage2 = new File("C:\\lo1.jpg");
          img1 = ImageIO.read(sourceimage1);
          img2 = ImageIO.read(sourceimage2);
```

the two images are black and white , and their dimensions are smaller than the two previous images `(lenna50 and lenna100)` 
**the lo.jpg and lo1.jpg are the same image to test the algorithm also they are in black and white** 
how can I change the code to make it work for any image dimension ?

Comment: Which row is number 77? I assume the code you posted is from Main.java

Comment: yes it is from Main.java the line is :  int rgb1 = img1.getRGB(i, j); i guess the error is in the getRGB ?

Comment: Error is not in getRGB. But the values you are passing in getRGB are most probably out of bound for either height or width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Toggle the i and j

in the following code as I have done below:

```
int rgb1 = img1.getRGB(j, i);
int rgb2 = img2.getRGB(j, i);
```

Comment: "Simple" but subtle one, +1

Comment: Good catch! I'd also recommend naming the variables `x` (for `j`) and `y` (for `i`), to make things more obvious. Modern IDEs would even warn you that you probably swapped the variables in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Your error clearly says that while reading rgb point as code in line `img1.getRGB(i, j);` it is going out of Array for image RGB. Check the values of i & j inside your inner for loop and check whether something you are doing wrong. As already Hirak pointed may be that you are not initializing your variables properly and so the reason it is going out of height or width.